# Magento2: issue with cron run \ privilages

Tags: magento2, cron

After upgrade magento to 2.4 I add privilages:

```
cd <your Magento install dir> 

// 644 permission for files
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; 
                   
// 755 permission for directory
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;    
                 
// 777 permission for var folder
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Still cron return error:

```
2021-01-02 22:39:08] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths: /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/.travis.yml.sample /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/app/functions.php /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/tests/functional/.gitignore /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/tests/functional/bootstrap.php /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/tests/functional/composer.json /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/tests/functional/credentials.xml.dist /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/tests/functional/etc /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/tests/functional/isolation.php /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/tests/functional/lib /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/tests/functional/phpunit.xml.dist /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/tests/functional/tests /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/tests/functional/testsuites/Magento /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/tests/functional/utils /home/user/domains/domian.com/public_html/dev/travis [] []
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Make sure ur cron user has the privilege to your magento directory.

Comment: How I can check or set privilage to root magento for cron ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command from the Magento root directory:

```
php -f bin/magento cron:install
```

After installing Cron, you view the job by running the following command:

```
crontab -l
```